# AASTEX631 - onecolumn: The bibliography runs over the footnotes in onecolumn format

Tags: bibliographies, footnotes, aastex

I am using `aastex631` in onecolumn format. However, the reference list is automatically in twocolumn mode. I have two footnotes towards the end (in the last appendix) and these footnotes appear in onecolumn format. Now the problem is the twocolumn reference list runs over the footnotes! This must be a bug. I think the problem would be avoided if I could force either the reference list to be in onecolumn or the footnotes to be in twocolumn. But I could not succeed with `aastex631`. Please help.
P.S. I am using a `.bib` file.

Answer (score 1):

```latex
\documentclass{aastex631}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\thebibliography}{\twocolumngrid}{}{}{}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{aasjournal}
\bibliography{sample631}
\end{document}
```

[image]